# For a cross section $\sigma\colon G/N\to G$, how is $\sigma(y)^{-1}\sigma(x)^{-1}\sigma(xy)$ called?

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a locally compact group, let $N$ be a closed normal subgroup of $G$, and let $\sigma\colon G/N\to G$ be a cross section. Let us define $\alpha\colon G/N\times G/N \to N$ by the formula
$$
\sigma(x)\sigma(y)\alpha(x,y)=\sigma(xy),
$$
for all $x,y\in G/N$.

Then $\alpha$ records how far $\sigma$ is from being multiplicative. Is there a standard name for $\alpha$? It seems to be a variant of a $2$-cocycle, but it is not the usual $2$-cocylce associated to a cross section.

Comment: It is exactly a cocycle, in nonabelian cohomology of groups.

Comment: Really? The usual cocycle for the section $\sigma$ is the map $\omega\colon G\times G/N\to N$, defined by the formula $\sigma(gy)\omega(g,y)=g\sigma(y)$. If $\sigma$ is multiplicative (which means that $G$ is a semidirect product), then $\alpha$ is trivial, but the cocycle $\omega$ need not be. How can this be?

Comment: I disagree, the usual notion of 2-cocycle in $H^2(G/N,N)$ is a function $G/N\times G/N \to N$, measuring exactly how $N\to G \to G/N$ fails to be a trivial extension. This is different to measuring if the extension is a split extension or not.

Comment: Ah I see. Thanks. But then what is "the cocycle" associated to the cross section? Maybe there are two. One measuring if the extension is split, and one measuring if the section is multiplicative.

Comment: Your second sentence is correct. The issue with "the cocycle" is that there seem to be more than one sort of cohomology lying around, one for each definition of cocycle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe David Roberts is correct that $\alpha$ is a $2$-cocycle representing an element of $H^2(G/N,N)$, and is the usual $2$-cocycle associated to this extension.

The confusion comes from the fact that $\omega$ is *not* a $2$-cocycle. Rather, it is called a cocycle because it can be thought of as a $1$-cocycle representing a class in $H^1 \bigl( G, \mathcal{F}(G/N; N) \bigr)$, where $\mathcal{F}(G/N; N)$ is the space of functions from $G/N$ to $N$. This is a group under pointwise multiplication, and $G$ acts on it via $\varphi^g(x) = \varphi(gx)$.

More precisely, define $\omega_g(x) = \omega(g,x)$, so $\omega_g \in \mathcal{F}(G/N; N)$ for each $g \in G$.  Then 
    $$ \sigma(ghx) \, \omega(gh,x) 
 = gh \, \sigma(x) 
 = g \cdot \sigma(hx) \, \omega(h,x)
 = \sigma(ghx) \, \omega(g, hx) \, \omega(h,x)
 ,$$
so $\omega_{gh} = (\omega_g)^h \cdot \omega_h$. This is precisely what it means to say that $\omega_g$ is a $1$-cocycle.

That $\omega$ is a $1$-cocycle (in the more general context of $G$-actions on principal bundles) is mentioned at the bottom of page 66 of R.J.Zimmer's book *Ergodic Theory and Semisimple Groups*.